# How to assign python variable for parent and variable for child

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I assign a python program to output a available list (i.e., List1, List2) based on the user input of the test level (i.e., P1, P2).

I tried doing this.

---

Python Code:

```
testing_lists = db.child("testlevel").shallow().get()

print(testing_lists.val())

choice_level = testing_lists.val()['P1']

print(choice_level)
```

---

Output:

> dict_keys(['P1', 'P2'])
>
> ....
>
> TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

I cannot get the data to be retrieved from P1.

[image: Image from firebase]

### Update (11 Nov)

Supposed I want to create an array for list 1 and list 2 in P1, what should i do?

i.e.,
How do I do this?

user input "P1".
output provides a={List1, List2}.

After which user input "List1"
output provides b={Word1(value), Word2(value), Word3(value)}

example of a run.

Input1: P1
Output1: List 1, List 2

Input2: List 1
Output2: Apple, Banana, Coconut

---

Python Code:

testing_lists = db.child("testlevel").get()

k=testing_lists.val()

print (k)

Output:

OrderedDict([('P1', {'list1': {'word1': 'apple', 'word2': 'banana', 'word3': 'coconut'}, 'list2': {'word1': 'ambulance', 'word2': 'bus', 'word3': 'car'}}), ('P2', {'list1': {'word1': 'apricot', 'word2': 'beetroot', 'word3': 'capsicum'}, 'list2': {'word1': 'apache', 'word2': 'bulldozer', 'word3': 'chinook'}})])

---

Afterwhich, I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: testing_lists = db.child("testlevel").shallow().get()
  print(testing_lists.val())
  choice_level = testing_lists.val()['P1']
  print(choice_level)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do `db.child("testlevel").shallow().get()` I'd expect the `testing_lists` variable to only contain the direct keys under `testlevel` and not the values under each key. If that's indeed the case, then `testing_lists.val()['P1']` makes no sense, because the value was never retrieved from the database to begin with.

If this hypothesis is correct, you'll want to `get()` without `shallow()`: `db.child("testlevel").get()`

Comment: Can I get your advice on the update I provided on 11 Nov. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Instead of describing that in words, can you show the code?